# Why should one use ClassCleanup?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Currently I'm testing out the Unit Test features of `.NET Framework` and therefore came across `[TestInitialize] [TestCleanup] [ClassInitialize]` and `[ClassCleanup]`. Why should I use `[ClassCleanup]` because I cannot come up with any scenarios where I could use `[ClassCleanup]` in a useful way.

I think it might be similar to `[TestCleanup]` which cleans up after every `[TestMethod]` but `[ClassCleanup]` is called after running through all tests and not each one (as explained to me). This is the reason why I don't know how to use it or whether to use it at all (right now I'm not using it at all).

Fell free to explain this to me and thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Just imagine you created some temp files in `ClassInitialize` for your test cases. You might want to get rid of them in the end.

Comment: That makes sense but it won't apply to my cases because I'm not creating any temp files

Comment: @JieBäf - If you're not creating any external resources then you don't need `ClassCleanup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use it to cleanup the resources that you created in `ClassInitialize`. Imagine you want to spin a database for your test class that all test methods should be able to use. You create it in `ClassInitialize` and destroy in `ClassCleanup`.

Comment: But if I finish up my tests, all the data set in `[ClassInitialize]` is removed or am I missing something?

Comment: Argh.. was just about to post this. At least half of the projects I typically work on set up tables/stored procs/etc to use over a given set of tests. We clean them up with `ClassCleanup`.

Comment: @JieBäf -No... what makes you think that? That is what the cleanup is for. You need to tell it what to cleanup. It doesn't just automatically run `ClassInitialize` in reverse.

Comment: Well once i ran through all tests, isn't all data saved to memory removed?

Comment: @JieBäf noone is gonna cleanup resources that you manually allocated. Yes, the CLR will call destructors and all that jazz, but any external resources (files, databases) are staying intact.

Comment: @JieBäf - Sure. But we're talking about resources outside of objects in visual studio. If you create a table in a local SQL Server instance for example, you need to manually DROP it when you're finished.

Comment: Ok, so `[ClassCleanup]` is for removing temporary data stored outside of memory but on the actual drive. That's probably why I never got any idea of using it since all my data is being stored and used in memory. Is there any other reason why one should use `[ClassCleanup]` or is it just for removing data which isn't saved to memory?

Comment: @JieBäf You may want to remove certain things from memory as well. Imagine you have some in-memory storage for your application. You might want to clean what the tests created in it so data doesn't interfere with other test classes.

Comment: Oh you are right, I can have multiple `TestClasses` and e.g. I use the same string in both classes but I modify it using tests it could result in an accepted string in both classes and allow a method to pass the test which would have failed if i cleaned up after all methods from class a were executed (never occured to me because I just have one UnitTest-Class atm)